# Creating Basemap for ArcGIS Online from Georeferenced .tiff

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online-basemaps

I have a GeoTIFF file that I would like to use as a basemap for an ArcGIS Online web map application. Is there a way to turn the TIFF into a basemap so that it can used for this purpose? Ideally, I would like to be able to use ArcGIS Pro for this, but that does not have to be the case.

The only documentation that I can find does not seem to include anything about this  (https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/windows/customize-basemaps.htm)

Comment: I’m sure you can do this by adding it to a Map that you publish but it may be expensive to host at ArcGIS.com. .

Comment: Custom Tiles https://community.esri.com/groups/geodev-germany/blog/2018/08/19/custom-tile-layers-in-agol-and-arcgis-pro